# Entity Framework - Code First Model Validation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

In my project, I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 with Code First Migrations.

When I make a change in the model, I can sync my database with these commands in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Add-Migration "MIGRATION-NAME"
PM> Update-Database
```

Right now I am making several changes in my model, is there any command I can run to validate my model?

Comment: what do you mean by validate?

Comment: @jjj I believe he is referring to validate option that we get in Model First approach.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to validate option that we get in Model First approach. For code first, there is no separate validate command, if Add-Migration fails that gives you the validation error. As this command is executed in transaction, all the partial changes by this command will be rolled-back in case of any error.